# Fatal error: cannot open file '-c= ' : No such file or directory (SPP, phantompeakqualtools)

Tags: c++, r, bioinformatics, sequencing

I am trying to run phantompeakqualtools in the terminal, I am using a WSL in Visual Studio Code.

I have followed all the steps and installed dependencies to use this program as listed here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/phantompeakqualtools/ and here: https://github.com/kundajelab/phantompeakqualtools

However when I try to execute, it says no such file or directory while clearly the file is there.

[image]

The file is in the correct format, a tagAlign.gz file. But somehow it can't find it. I also tried to run it as sudo but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that `$(which run_spp.R)` returns non-empty string?

Comment: *"clearly the file is there"* -- this is clear to you? It's not to me. I do not see a file named `-c=OT1_test9.filt.nodup.sample.25M.SE.taAlign.gz` in your directory listing. The closest I see is `OT1_test9.filt.nodup.sample.25M.SE.taAlign.gz`.

Comment: I believe @Yksisarvinen is correct. I think you need to replace `$(which run_spp.R)` with `run_spp.R`. `run_spp.R` is probably not marked as executable.

Comment: A second solution may be to type `chmod a+x run_spp.R` to set the execute bit on the .R file so that which finds it.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it worked to run just run_spp.R instead of the $(which run_spp.R)